# Unexpected relation and node COUNT in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

Whenever I am using a query to get the count of a specific node, I always get the number greater than 1 even though there is only one distinct type of that node existing.

Sample query:

`MATCH (p)-[rel]->(v:myDistinctNode) RETURN COUNT(v)`

**Output**: 80

`MATCH (p)-[rel]->(v:myDistinctNode) RETURN COUNT(DISTINCT v)`

**Output**: 1

I see different results while using DISTINCT, but I cannot use DISTINCT all the time. Why I am seeing this and how can I avoid it? Thanks!
Neo4j Kernel-Version: 3.5.14

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you need to use a collect statement to make it work.

```
MATCH (p)<-[rel]-(v:myDistinctNode) WITH collect(v) AS nodes RETURN count(nodes)
```

This should return one.
I'm not a cypher expert, but I believe the reason it doesn't work is that the cypher result seems more like a table where in one row you have p, another row you have r, and the last row you have v. Even though v is a unique entity, there are still 80 rows that have v.

Comment: Oh I get it. Thanks for the solution! @bischrob

Comment: My pleasure to help.